# Android null pointer exception and Database Update

Tags: android, android-layout

I keep getting this error java.null.pointer exception When ever i trie to run this code please help me how to solve this problem and update my database values.
Here is my code
Main activity class

```
package dom.example.database_exp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();

    SQLiteDatabase db =openOrCreateDatabase("Test", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    obj.Update(1, "Raza", "17", "Nohting"); 
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName FROM test WHERE ID = 1 ",null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  EditText dis=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  String  result =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName")); 

   dis.setText("You have found "+result);

   db.close();

    /**    EditText dis=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       //Creating and opening the  database
     SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("RamDB", MODE_PRIVATE,null);
     //Creating table with 3 columns
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(ID INTEGER PK NOT NULL FirstName      VARCHAR,LastName VARCHAR,Age INT(3));");
                 **/

  }



 public int Update (int sid, String name, String age, String course)
  {
    String FirstName = "FirstName";
    String LastName = "LastName";
    String test = "test";
    String ID = "ID";
    // String _id = "1" ;
    SQLiteDatabase db =openOrCreateDatabase("Test", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    ContentValues pau = new ContentValues();
    pau.put(FirstName, name);



   return db.update(test, pau,ID + "=" + sid, null);

   }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
     return true;
   }
   }
```

My xml file

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
     </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need the stack trace to check where is the error. though the constuctor call `MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();` within your OnCreate method seems really strange. As far as I know you do not need to call the constructor of you Activity

and you can refer to your activity call `this`

Try to remove the `MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();` and `this.Update(1, "Raza", "17", "Nohting");` also there is no need to run openOrCreateDatabase twice, you are running it on the OnCreate and on the method.

In any case, check your trace  `adb logcat` to have a better understanding where the code is failing.